# Specify TestNG test groups in Scala

Tags: scala, testng

I'm trying to assign groups to TestNG classes and methods in a Scala environment (in Eclipse)

```
@Test(groups="register")
class RegisterTest {
...
```

but am encountering the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch; found : java.lang.String("register") required: 
Array[java.lang.String]
- annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: "register"{<error>}
```

I've tried applying groups to individual Scala methods but still encounter the same error.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

The`@Test`annotation works as long as it doesn't specify any parameters (same error if `dependsOnMethods`parameter is specified).

`@DataProvider`annotation also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ScalaDoc](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/index.html#org.scalatest.testng.TestNGSuite) gives the following example:

```
@Test(groups = Array("com.mycompany.groups.SlowTest"))
def funTest() {
  sb.append("fun!")
  assert(sb.toString === "ScalaTest is fun!")
  assert(lb.isEmpty)
}
```

That seems to match the error you get.

Comment: And the prize goes to... the slice of cheese. Thanks